# getting variables into ajax function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have an AJAX function triggerd by a click which basically copies one table row into another table.

The problem I am having is that I get the required variables from the original table row before the AJAX request however these variables don't seem to be passed to the success function and they come out as `undefined`.

Is there anyway to pass the variables to the function ?

```
$('.addfile_popup').on('click', '.add2_fl', function(){
    var file_id1=$(this).data('file');
    var id=$('.useri').val();
    var file_name1=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    var upload_date1=$(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text();
    var upload_desc=$(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(2).text();
    var job_idx=$(this).data('jid');
    //write to appointment database
    var data="job_id="+job_idx+"&file_id="+file_id1+"&user_id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"admin_includes/prepend_files.php",
        data:data,
        success:function(html){
            var ups='';
            ups+='<tr data-file='+file_id1+'><td width="40%">'+file_name1+'</td><td>'+upload_date1+'</td><td>'+upload_desc+'</td><td><a href="sym.php?doc_id='+file_id1+'" class="view2_fl">VIEW FILE</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del2_fl">DELETE</a></td></tr>';
            $(ups).prependTo('.app_table');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.addfile_popup').on('click', '.add2_fl', function(){
    var file_id1=$(this).data('file');
    var id=$('.useri').val();
    var file_name1=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    var upload_date1=$(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text();
    var upload_desc=$(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(2).text();
    var job_idx=$(this).data('jid');
    //write to appointment database
    var data="job_id="+job_idx+"&file_id="+file_id1+"&user_id="+id;

    // closure function that wrap your variables
    function success(file_id1, file_name1, upload_date1 ... ) {
         return function(html) {  
            var ups='';
            ups+='<tr data-file='+file_id1+'><td width="40%">'+file_name1+'</td><td>'+upload_date1+'</td><td>'+upload_desc+'</td><td><a href="sym.php?doc_id='+file_id1+'" class="view2_fl">VIEW FILE</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del2_fl">DELETE</a></td></tr>';
            $(ups).prependTo('.app_table');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"admin_includes/prepend_files.php",
        data:data,
        success: success(file_id1, file_name1, upload_date1 ...)
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 You are missing a brace but this is a good solution I think.

Comment: Rather that concat a string supply data as an object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a closure. You can read about them here: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

This should work:

```
$('.addfile_popup').on('click', '.add2_fl', function(){
  var me = this;

  (function() {
    var file_id1=$(me).data('file');
    var id=$('.useri').val();
    var file_name1=$(me).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    var upload_date1=$(me).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text();
    var upload_desc=$(me).closest('tr').children('td').eq(2).text();
    var job_idx=$(me).data('jid');

    //write to appointment database
    var data="job_id="+job_idx+"&file_id="+file_id1+"&user_id="+id;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"admin_includes/prepend_files.php",
    data: {
      job_id: job_idx,
      file_id: file_id1,
      user_id: id
    },  
    success:function(html){
        var ups='';
        ups+='<tr data-file='+file_id1+'><td width="40%">'+file_name1+'</td><td>'+upload_date1+'</td><td>'+upload_desc+'</td><td><a href="sym.php?doc_id='+file_id1+'" class="view2_fl">VIEW FILE</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del2_fl">DELETE</a></td></tr>';

    $(ups).prependTo('.app_table');
    }
    });//end ajax

    })();

});
```

Note also I've changed how you pass data to the AJAX call.

Comment: +1 If you don't need access to the variables anywhere else then a closure is the best way. JavaScript closures are quite powerful and are definitely worth researching regardless.

Comment: it does not seem to work. Still not finding the initial variables.